# definition of image and preimage

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Claim: Suppose $f : A \to B$ and $S$ and $T$ are subsets of $A$. Prove that if $S \subseteq T$ then $f(S) \subseteq f(T)$.

Proof. Suppose $f : A \to B$, $S$ and $T$ are subsets of $A$ and $S \subseteq T$. Let $y \in f(S)$. Then there is $x \in S$ such that $y = f(x)$. Since $S \subseteq T$, $x \in T$. So there is $x \in T$ such that $y = f(x)$, and therefore $y \in f(T)$ by definition of image. Since $y$ was an arbitrary element of $f(S)$, we have $f(S) \subseteq f(T)$.

However, I do NOT understand why "Let $y \in f(S)$. Then there is $x \in S$ such that $y = f(x)$" or "there is $x \in T$ such that $y = f(x)$,and therefore $y \in f(T)$ by definition of image" is true? How exactly is the definition of image/preimage applied to those to statements?

Answer (score 0):

Given a function $f : A \to B$ and a subset $U \subseteq A$, the image $f(U)$ of $U$ is defined by
$$f(U) = \{ f(x) \mid x \in U \} = \{ y \in B \mid y=f(x) \text{ for some } x \in U \}$$
So here you just need to apply the definition. If $y \in f(S)$ then $y=f(x)$ for some $x \in S$; this is just the definition of $f(S)$. Since $S \subseteq T$, it follows that $x \in T$. But then $y=f(x)$ and $x \in T$ so that $y \in f(T)$ again by definition of image.

Sorry if I'm just rewording your problem, but the thing you don't understand really is just the definition of image.

Comment: "But then y=f(x)y=f(x) and x∈Tx∈T so that y∈f(T)y∈f(T) again by definition of image."

Does this mean that y=f(x) and x∈T, moreover T is a subset of A so f:A to B implies that y is an element of B, which fits the full definition. (becuase in the proof, it skipped the part where is mentioned y is an element of B which is part of the definition)

also, f(U)={f(x)∣x∈U}={y∈B∣y=f(x) for some x∈U}, this definition goes both ways right? Thanks for your detailed explanantion.

Comment: or can definition be shortened to this? f(U)={f(x)∣x∈U}={y∈B∣y=f(x) for some x∈U}={y∣y=f(x) for some x∈U} since y being an element of B is implied through y=f(x) for some x∈U anyways